# Does Java handle HTTPS encoding behind the scenes when I call my SOAP service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, jax-ws

In Java, I am building a stand alone web service client that manipulates records in a cloud based CRM by using its SOAP API.  I generated my classes using the wsimport utility with WSDLs that all have addresses prefixed with https in the port binding section of the WSDL. Is Java handling behind the scenes all the wire-level security simply because the address is https? If so, how can I confirm that the SOAP message is being encrypted?  My code does work, and I have not needed to worry about security until now, because I am developing in a staging environment with temporary passwords.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `https` in the URL will almost always do the trick.  Even if your code is not capable of https, the webserver at the other end will almost never allow you to talk in HTTP when using the HTTPS port.  At least, I've never seen one that does.

It's not a 100% guarantee that you'd bet your business on, but it is close.

If the code you write works on any website that does require https, you are the rest of the way there in terms of assurances.

You can confirm the traffic is encrypted by running a traffic analyzer aka packet sniffer.